# Disable multiple icons in Dropzone when uploading multiple files

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

The default configuration in Dropezone.js displays a separate icon and progress bar for each file being uploaded. So if you drag a folder containing 100 files into dropzone, there will be 100 icons on the screen which doesn't look good.

I'd rather have just one icon and progress bar to show the aggregate progress of multiple files.

Is there a setting in the Dropzone configuration that can do this, if not how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Seem to me that it is not possible, but you can create your own total upload progress bar.

You only need to use the event of DropzoneJS "totaluploadprogress" and  a widget to show the progress bar, for example "jquery ui progress bar":

- [jquery ui progress bar](https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/)
- [DropzoneJS totaluploadprogress event](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-totaluploadprogress)

Answer (score 1):

you can compress the folder to a zip/rar file, and upload it with dropzonejs, this is another way around.